# How to fix Rails respond_with model that is not namespaced?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an API with Rails. The controllers are namespaced with `Api::V1` but the models are not. I'm adding `responds_to :json` and passing the model to `respond_with` but it fails when generating the route from the model. It should be `api_v1_resource_url`, but it is simply returning `resource_url`. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the relevant code in your question, try this:

`respond_with(:api, @yourmodel)`

I'm presuming your code is something like the following:

```
def Api::V1
  responds_to :json
  def create
    @yourmodel = YourObject.new(params[:yourmodel])
    @yourmodel.save
    respond_with(:api, @yourmodel) // TRY THIS
  end
end
```